# How can I get country data from a NC (NetCDF) file containing global data in the form of longitudes and latitude?

Tags: python, python-3.x, geopandas, netcdf, python-xarray

I have a temperature data from a NetCDF file from NASA's [website](https://data.giss.nasa.gov/gistemp/maps/) for global level. The data is in this [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1NTg-WvU1SZZJPv_FudTmjNiQEppgHrTc?usp=sharing) in my google drive.

I am able to open the data using:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
data = Dataset("../data/amaps_robinson_1000km.nc")
```

The `data` looks as shown below when I print it:
[image]

`data.variables` yields me following:

```
{'lon': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
 float32 lon(lon)
     long_name: Longitude
     standard_name: longitude
     units: degrees_east
 unlimited dimensions: 
 current shape = (180,)
 filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used,
 'lat': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
 float32 lat(lat)
     long_name: Latitude
     standard_name: latitude
     units: degrees_north
 unlimited dimensions: 
 current shape = (90,)
 filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used,
 'TEMPANOMALY': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
 float32 TEMPANOMALY(lat, lon)
     long_name: Temperature anomaly
     standard_name: surface_temperature_anomaly
     missing_value: 9999.0
     units: K
 unlimited dimensions: 
 current shape = (90, 180)
 filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used}
```

I am able to access the longitude, latitude and temperature data using

```
lons = data.variables["lon"][:]
lats = data.variables["lat"][:]
temp_anomaly = data.variables["TEMPANOMALY"][:]
```

I am also able to plot it using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib as mpl

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (12, 6))

ax = plt.axes(projection = ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax.set_global()
ax.coastlines(resolution = "10m", lw = 1)
#ax.gridlines(linestyle = "--", color = "black")


#Set contour levels, then draw the plot and a colorbar
clevs = np.arange(-4, 5)
cmap = "coolwarm"

#Plot filled contours
plt.contourf(lons, lats, 
             temp_anomaly,
             clevs,
             transform = ccrs.PlateCarree(),
             cmap = cmap
             #cmap options for temperature anomaly: coolwarm, RdBu, bwr
            )


plt.title("(°C) Anomaly in 2021 vs 1951-1980")


cb = plt.colorbar(ax = ax,
                  orientation = "horizontal",
                  pad = 0.02,
                  aspect = 10,  #ratio of long to short dimension
                  shrink = 0.5 #Fraction by which to multiply the size of the colorbar
                 )


cb.set_label("°C", size = 12, rotation = 0, labelpad = 15)

cb.ax.tick_params(labelsize = 10)

plt.show()
```

It looks as follows:
[image]

However, I would like to get the data for individual countries like Germany, France, Nepal, India, etc. and plot them by country individually instead of clipping them on the map of the world. How can I get the data for the countries individually?

Comment: what do you mean exactly when you say you want to get the data for those countries instead of clipping them? The data is gridded, so you'll need to apply some sort of transform (land- or population- weighted mean, for example). check out [regionmask](https://regionmask.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) - it's designed to integrate with [xarray](https://xarray.pydata.org/) to facilitate transitioning from gridded to polygon-based data definitions.

Comment: What I meant is that you can clip the map of a country say Germany from the map of the world and plot it. But I don't want to do that. Instead, I would like to get the temperature data for Germany from the file and plot the data on the map of Germany.

Comment: got it. yep I'd take a look at regionmask